# MediatR 3.0.1 possible bug? Cannot get IAsyncRequestHandler working

Tags: asp.net-core, mediatr

I am getting the following error message when executing IRequest with IAsyncRequestHandler.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[TestProject.Domain.Requests.Users.CreateUserRequest,TestProject.Domain.Requests.Users.CreateUserResponse]' has been registered.'
```

This is how i register it in the startup class

```cs
// Add framework services.
services.AddMvc();
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CreateUserRequest).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

CreateUserRequest and Response

```cs
public class CreateUserRequest : IRequest<CreateUserResponse>
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class CreateUserResponse
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Request handler

```cs
public class CreateUserRequestHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<CreateUserRequest, CreateUserResponse>
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;


    public CreateUserRequestHandler()
    {

    }

    public async Task<CreateUserResponse> Handle(CreateUserRequest request)
    {
        //create the user and assign it to the organisation
        var user = new User
        {
            Email = request.EmailAddress,
            OrganisationUsers = new List<OrganisationUser> { new OrganisationUser { OrganisationId = request.OrganisationId } }
        };

        //create new user with password.
        await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, request.Password);

        //create response.
        var response = new CreateUserResponse{UserId = user.Id, EmailAddress = user.Email};

        return response;
    }
}
```

Controller class

```cs
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public UserController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<CreateUserResponse> Post(CreateUserRequest request)
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(request);
    }
}
```

the error occurs inside the controller class it does not hit the async request handler.

Is there anything wrong with the DI registration? I have looked at the examples but could not find anything specific to aspnet core.

Comment: Is the handler defined in the same assembly as the request/response?

Comment: Hi Mickael, what do you have to do if the query and the response model are in one project and the handler in another project?